# Facebook graph api doesn't response on real host but work fine in localhost

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I had been using my written script for months and just from few days ago facebook stop responding ( it take forever to loads ) when the request is made from my host, but the same exact codes work fine when run in localhost.

I had been using curl method to get the group feed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/group/members

```
file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/489360131076423/feed/?access_token=APPID|SECRETCODE")
```

which still work fine in localhost but not in server.  Then i also tried using "PHP SDK" method still having the same problem.

My setting in facebook developer is too seems to correct (it was working before too) as I have two domain allowed in App Domains setting which are  "localhost" and "xxxxxxxx.im"   ( my domain is .im not .com and obviously in xxxx i have my domain name written)

The question is 
1. Can anyone suggest what could be the problem ?
2. Any suggestion for debugging this? because i don't get response at all. So no idea about any request error :(

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you using the exact code you posted here on your server? there's a chance that your server IP is blacklisted

Comment: yeah it is the exact code (i always sync local-host) . I thought of about being blacklisted too but how do i know exactly is it really being blacklisted ( i don't find in app developer panel )  BUT i do get response sometime (but too rare) kinda like 5% chance to get response.

Comment: But doesn't facebook ban APP rather than IP ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ob_start(); function in the starting of page

Comment: that doesn't help, i don't see any change :(